# Why does this Excel formula return 0.042361? =Sum(Indirect(Address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In sheet3 columns A,B,C,D are the value of row numbers. Thus, A1 to D1 contain 1, A2 to D2 contain 2,...etc.

Why does the following formula in G2 of Sheet2 return 0.042361? All numbers are integers. There are no decimals in Sheet3. Why and how sum returns a decimal number? Thanks.

Formula in G2:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet3!"&ADDRESS(1,ROW()))&":"&INDIRECT("Sheet3!"&ADDRESS(1,1+ROW())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is one `INDIRECT()` too much, giving you the range "1:1".

Getting rid of it leaves you with a range like

```
Sheet3!$B$1:Sheet3!$C$1
```

but the correct way is

```
Sheet3!$B$1:$C$1
```

So your formula needs to be

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet3!"&ADDRESS(1;ROW())&":"&ADDRESS(1;1+ROW())))
```